# C++ Kill a Thread In Destructor

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, access-violation

I have a class that starts another thread that accesses some of its data at constant intervals. This means I have two threads that access the same data (the original thread and the newly created thread). This introduces the need for a mutex. All goes well until the destructor of the class is called (at the end of the program) and the memory locations are no longer valid. At this point the new thread attempts to access the data and gets an access violation error (obviously).

What I would like to do is stop the thread in the destructor, or have the thread stop once it "notices" that the class instance has been destroyed.

Here is the simplified thread code (typedefs used for brevity):

```
void myClass::StartThread() {
    auto threadFunc = [&, this]() {
        while (true) {
            time_point now = steady_clock::now();
            if (chro::duration_cast<chro::milliseconds>(now - this->m_lastSeedTime).count() > INTERVAL) {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lockGuard(this->m_mut);
                this->m_lastSeedTime = now;
                this->accessData();
            }
        }
    };
    std::thread thread(threadFunc);
    thread.detach();
```

of course if I am just mishandling this in some obvious way, please let me know as well.

Comment: Why are you destroying an object when it is still needed? The solution is pretty simple -- don't do that. Destroy an object when, and only when, it's no longer needed. There are lots of mechanisms to do that. One is `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It is no longer needed. It is the end of the program. I need to destroy it sometime. At that point, the other thread will complain.

Comment: If the other thread will complain if you destroy it, it is too early to destroy it. Since the other thread needs it, the other thread should be doing something to prevent its destruction. Clean shutdown, if required, has to be designed in. You have a `while(true)` loop there with no way to exit it -- how can you cleanly shut that down? (Also, the code shown burns the CPU needlessly, crippling performance of the entire system. Is that the real code?)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz no, the other thread needs to stop when the object is destroyed. That is the stopping condition. It doesn't need it anymore. Even if it did, and I put the destroy logic in the other thread, the first thread would complain in the same way and this would lead to the same exact issue. Clean shutdown is exactly what this question is asking about.

Comment: No. You don't destroy an object while it might still be in use. That is what is creating the problem. If you make the object self-destruct when it is no longer needed, all you need to do is make the threads stop doing work when there is no work left for them to do, which is a natural and simple thing.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That is what I am asking about. How can I make the thread stop doing work when the object self destructs?

Comment: The thread needs to know when there is no work left for it to do. If that's only when the program shuts down, a common way to do it is to have a "shutdown manager" that tracks all objects that need to be shutdown. Then your `while(true)` becomes `while(shutdownManager->shouldRun())`. Then just call the shutdown managers "shutdown" function in your shutdown process. As I said, clean shutdown has to be designed in if it is needed. But having the object destroy itself when no longer needed may be all you need here. Then each object just has to shut itself down.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226361/discussion-between-david-schwartz-and-fishrec).

Comment: this is a possible solution but a bit cumbersome for the small task it has to do. I'd rather stop the thread in the destructor of the class if this is possible.

Comment: *no, the other thread needs to stop when the object is destroyed.*  You have that entirely backwards - the other thread needs to stop before it's safe to destroy the object it's using.  Blowing the object out from under the thread is a good way to invoke undefined behavior and end your entire process abruptly with a `SIGSEGV` or something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a thread to die, you should ask it to exit. It's the only reliable way to do it cleanly.

Just change

```
while (true)
```

to

```
while(this->keepRunning)
```

and synchronize it appropriately. Either don't detach the thread (so the destructor can join it) or add some way for the thread to indicate that it has exited (so the destructor can wait for it).

Oh, and instead of spinning, the thread should probably sleep. In that case, if you don't want the destructor to also block, you need some way to interrupt the sleep: using a timed wait on a condition variable for your sleep makes this easy.

Comment: but accessing this->keepRunning will throw an error as well once the destructor is called.

Comment: Not until the destructor _completes_, which is why the destructor must wait until the background thread has exited.

Answer (score 2):

@Useless' answer is correct. Here is how exactly you can do it:

```
class myClass{
    ...
private:
    std::thread m_thread;
    std::atomic_bool m_keepRunning{true};
    ....
};


void myClass::StartThread() {
    auto threadFunc = [&, this]() {
        while (m_keepRunning) {
            time_point now = steady_clock::now();
            if (chro::duration_cast<chro::milliseconds>(now - this->m_lastSeedTime).count() > INTERVAL) {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lockGuard(this->m_mut);
                if(!m_keepRunning) break; // destructor called, don't access data
                this->m_lastSeedTime = now;
                this->accessData();
            }
        }
    };
    m_thread = std::thread(threadFunc);
}

myClass::~myClass()
{
    m_keepRunning = false;
    m_mutex.unlock(); // make sure we don't wait in the loop for the lock
    if(m_thread.joinable()) m_thread.join();
    
    // do other cleaning
}
```

Another point is, when you always wait for `INTERVAL`, it will cause a cumulative delay in time. Let's say your interval is 50 ms. When your CPU has too much work to do or accessData function takes too much time, you won't be able to run the next iteration exactly in 50 ms. Let's say it will be 52 msecs, which is a 2 msecs delay. These delays will add up in time and will effect your precision.

Instead, you could do:

```
time_point waitUntil = steady_clock::now() + initialWaitTime;
while(m_keepRunning){
    if(steady_clock::now() >= waitUntil)
    {
        // ... do your work
        waitUntil = waitUntil + chro::milliseconds(INTERVAL)
    }
}
```

Also @Useless is correct again for the timed waiting part. Spinning will cause a heavy load on your core. Instead, you should use a conditional or timed_mutex. But the advice above is still valid. Instead of using `sleep_for`, go for the `sleep_until` one.

Comment: m_keeprunning should be atomic

Comment: thank you. I wound up implementing a version of this based on some helpful conversation from a commenter. Another remark made above is that I should sleep the thread rather than keep a loop continuously running, which I also did. The precision issue happens not to concern me for this use case but thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Killing threads does not work. The problem is that if you do kill a thread, it could be in the middle of a multiple step operation that should be performed as an atomic operation, leaving your program in an invalid state. Instead, signal the other thread to commit suicide, and wait for it to die.